# is time.time() a reliable way to profile scripts?

Tags: python

I usually do this to get an idea of the execution time of some computation:

```
import time

t0 = time.time()
some_computation()
t1 = time.time()
dt = (t1 - t0) * 1000
print("execution time: {} ms".format(dt))
```

Is this a reliable way to measure execution time? Assuming there is no fancy async stuff in `some_computation()`, is there anything else I should be aware of? I think there is a difference between just clock time and thread execution time. I don't know too much about it. If `time.time()` is a bad idea to profile scripts, what's a better approach?

Comment: `timeit` module is much better. It needs more work though. to really profile scripts you need a python profiler

Comment: It depends of the accuracy that you need. If the resolution provided by time() (which comes from the OS) is good enough for you, then time() is OK.

Comment: My main concern is that it could be measuring time that the thread was not executing because the OS decided to execute other threads. Also, what are some good python profilers?